# Can I create something to run a google home command when I get a certain phone notification?

Tags: global, google-home

I am a volunteer firefighter and we have a mobile app that alerts us when we get an emergency call. Is there a way for me to turn on a light that is controlled via google home when my phone receives that notification? If so, how do I accomplish this? I have some experience with coding but not enough to get me through this, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way for me to turn on a light that is controlled via google home when my phone receives that notification?

Such automation, which combines customized applications with Google Home, is not supported in the smart home integration currently.

Having said that, from what you said, you seem to own the mobile app and probably the server too. If that’s the case, I can think of an alternative way which could fulfill your requirement:

1. First off, get some smart lights which are controllable via APIs. Try to google “programmable smart lights” to get more ideas.
2. Call the API to control smart lights mentioned in (1) when a notification is sent.

Theoretically this should work. It doesn’t involve Google Assistant at all though.